# Pthread_create segmentation faults when more than 12 threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a C++ program that sums numbers from 0 to n, using t threads. N and T are passed as command line args. I am using a for loop that creates the pthreads and a second for loop that rejoins the main to them. The program executes fine when I use less than 11 or 12 threads. For example, on input 100 10, it returns 5050. When I use more than 11-12 threads, it causes a segmentation fault and crashes. I cant seem to figure out why. There are some lines in my code I was using for debugging, such as printing to the prompt, etc. Any tips are appreciated!

```
int n = 0;
int t = 0;
unsigned long gsum = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;

void *sum(void *Index)
{
    int index = (int)(int *) Index; 
    int threadSum = 0;
    int k;
    int lowerBound, upperBound; //used to find range of numbers to sum

    //printf("I am here: %d \n",index);

    if (index == t - 1) {
        lowerBound = (n/t)*(t-1);
        upperBound = n; 
    } else {
        lowerBound = (n/t)*index;
        upperBound = (n/t)*(index+1)-1;
    }

    for (k = lowerBound; k < upperBound + 1; k++) {
        threadSum = threadSum + k;
    }

    // Critical Section
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexsum);
    gsum = gsum + threadSum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexsum);    

    pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int i, k, j;
pthread_t sumThreads [t];


for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if(i == 1)
        n = atoi(argv[i]);
    if(i == 2)
        t = atoi(argv[i]);
}

if (n < 0 || t <= 0 || argc != 3) {
    printf("Invalid or missing parameters! \n");
    exit(0); 
}

for (k = 0; k < t; k++) {
    int nt = -1;    
    nt = pthread_create(&sumThreads[k], NULL, sum, (void*)k);
    printf("%d \n", nt);
}

for (j = 0; j < t; j++) {
    int rj = -1;    
    rj = pthread_join (sumThreads[j], NULL);
    printf("%d \n", rj);
}    

printf("Total Sum: %lu \n",gsum);
return 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger, e.g. `gdb`, to see exactly where it segfaults and why?

Comment: This is going to be one of those variable capture thingies..

Comment: Ah, the problem is much simpler... You're initializing `sumThreads` to be of length `t`, but `t` is initially set to zero. You should allocate `sumThreads` to the correct length only after having parsed `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialized `t` to be zero at the top of your program, so this line:

```
pthread_t sumThreads [t];
```

is not allocating an array large enough to hold the thread identifiers. Thus, you have buffer overrun when storing the identifiers, and your are reading past the buffer in your `thread_join` loop.

You are using a feature called *variable length array* (or VLA) which became part of the C language in the 1999 revision to the standard. C++ has not adopted VLA, so you are using a compiler extension. If you want your code to be compliant with C++, you should use a vector instead.

```
std::vector<pthread_t> sumThreads;

// ...after t gets initialized
sumThreads.resize(t);
```

Comment: Wow, talk about a rookie mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @nav_jan: VLA is part of C99, and is a common extension of C++ compilers as a result, even though it is not part of the standard. I'll clarify my post.

Comment: @obzezzed350: Making mistakes is part of learning. Keep it up. +1 on your question from me.

Answer (score 0):

In c/c++ this type of code does not work:

```
int i=10:
int arr[i];
```

Avoid doing this. If this type of code was valid we would no longer need malloc..
This is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This compiles and runs successfully with three C99 compilant C compilers: GCC, Intel C Compiler and Sun/Oracle C compiler. It compiles as C++ code with GCC and Intel C++ Compiler. Only the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler errs about non-constant expression used as array size. So user315052 is right.

Comment: This is illegal in C89 and C++ but perfectly legal in C99.  It's a feature called *variable-length arrays* (VLAs).